# How to NServiceBus Publish() in Fixed interval

Tags: nservicebus

Is it possble to configure the Publisher to run in fixed interval, say every hour?  In the example I downloaded from the NServiceBus web site, the publisher publishes whenever a user hit enter key.  So, instead of that, I would like to publish a message every hour.

Thanks.

Comment: I think I can just add a timer and have publisher publishes when the time event fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a timer from an IWantToRunAtStartup class's Run method.  Then publish to the bus every time the timer fires.

Comment: I made a simple and pretty slick solution to scheduling recurring tasks in an NServiceBus service this way, and it works like a charm. You can see more here: http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/1507